# Каким образом можно очистить кэш всех приложений на устройстве Android?

Tags: java, android, кэширование

Я решил разработать приложение, которое очищает кэш всех приложений, установленных на устройстве. Я разобрался в том, каким образом можно очищать кэш своего собственного приложения. Каким образом можно провернуть это для остальных программ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605604/9363441 - вероятнее всего никак не получится, разве что через рут  и другие костыли

Answer (score 3):

Стороннее приложение не может удалить кэш другого приложения начиная с Android 6.0+. Уровень защиты Manifest.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE изменен с **"dangerous"** на **"signature | privileged"** или **"system | signature"** в Android 6.0+.

Теперь только системные приложения, подписанные ключом прошивки, могут иметь это разрешение.

Если приложение не установлено как системное приложение или у вас нет root прав, вы не сможете удалить кэш приложений в версии Android 6.0+.

Как приложение "Настройки" справляется с этим?
Давайте посмотрим на код. В строках `AppStorageSettings.java` 172 - 178 мы видим:

```
if (v == mClearCacheButton) {
    // Lazy initialization of observer
    if (mClearCacheObserver == null) {
        mClearCacheObserver = new ClearCacheObserver();
    }
    mPm.deleteApplicationCacheFiles(mPackageName, mClearCacheObserver);
}
```

Итак, приложение «Настройки» использует скрытый метод `PackageManager.deleteApplicationCacheFiles(String, IPackageDataObserver)`. Он может сделать это, потому что он имеет разрешение системного уровня `"android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA"`(разрешение, которое не может иметь стороннее приложение).

**Внешний кэш**

Однако очистка внешнего кэша все еще поддерживается.
Вы можете запросить разрешение `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, получить все установленные пакеты `PackageManager`, получить каталог внешнего кэша приложения и удалить каталог.

**Root доступ**

Конечно, если у вас есть root-доступ, вы можете удалить кэш другого приложения. Вот быстрый пример использования root-доступа для удаления всего кэша приложения:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : installedApplications) {
  try {
    Context packageContext = createPackageContext(applicationInfo.packageName, 0);
    List<File> directories = new ArrayList<>();
    directories.add(packageContext.getCacheDir());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
      Collections.addAll(directories, packageContext.getExternalCacheDirs());
    } else {
      directories.add(packageContext.getExternalCacheDir());
    }

    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("rm -rf");
    for (File directory : directories) {
      command.append(" \"" + directory.getAbsolutePath() + "\"");
    }

    Shell.SU.run(command.toString());
  } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException wtf) {
  }
}
```